# How to upgrade to IPv6 for AWS EC2?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ipv6, ipv4

Starting yesterday, AWS is charging for IP addresses (IPv4). I would like to upgrade my EC2 instances to IPv6, but I must be missing the docs on how to do that?

I can't seem to get an EC2 instance with an IPv6 address without having an IPv4 address?

I can only seem to get a *private* IPv6, but that just replaces one problem with another, as now I need *another* EC2 instance to do NAT, and an IPv4 address on that one anyway! So, that doesn't really solve anything.

How can I upgrade from IPv4 to IPv6 for EC2?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In AWS I think all IPv6 addresses are public, but you can make them non-routable in private subnets. You probably want a publicly routable IPv6 address, a private IPv4 address and no public IPv4 address. With this setup your website won't be accessible over IPv4 unless you provide some kind of gateway.

I made these changes a while back. My EC2 instance has IPv6, private IPv4, and I use CloudFlare as a gateway / proxy / cache. CloudFlare makes the website available on IPv4 or IPv6. It works well. I had to change my Nginx configuration a little to accept IPv6 only.

AWS has a useful tutorial [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/vpc-migrate-ipv6.html). The broad steps are:

- Associate an IPv6 CIDR block with your VPC and subnets
- Update your route tables
- Update your security group rules
- Assign IPv6 addresses to your instances